# How can I add an Zoom in/out event listener to an openlayers map?

Tags: google-maps, javascript

I am trying to hide and show certain layers of an open layers map at different zoom levels so that for example only one of all the layers on the map is visible at zoom level 20. I can't seem to find a way to create a behaviour that gets called when the user zooms in or out of the map, any ideas?